# No value given for one or more required Parameter OLEDB Exception

Tags: c#

Previously My Code is working Correctly but now it is throwing the error :

```
No value given for one or more  required Parameter OLEDB Exception
```

Code:

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
OleDbConnection excelConnection;
try
{
     if (Request.Files["FileUpload"].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName);
                    String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName);
                    if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        string currentPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName);




                        {
                            string mappedUploadPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFolder"), fileName);
                            if (System.IO.File.Exists(mappedUploadPath))
                                System.IO.File.Delete(mappedUploadPath);

                            Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(mappedUploadPath);

                            // Create connection string to Excel work book
                            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + mappedUploadPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                            //Creating an entityconnection
                            using (EntityConnection sqlConnectionString =
                            new EntityConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
                            {

                                excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                                excelConnection.Open();
                                OleDbDataReader dReader;


                                //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
                                //PromotionMaster
                                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [SKU],[SupplierId],[Price],[Validity],[LastUpdated],[EnteredBy],[Quantity],[CrediteTermId],[Approved],[DeliveryDate],[ETA],[CommModeId] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
                                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkPromotionMaster = new SqlBulkCopy(((SqlConnection)sqlConnectionString.StoreConnection).ConnectionString);

                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.DestinationTableName = "TempPriceList";
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("SKU", "SKU");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("SupplierId", "SupplierId");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("Validity", "Validity");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("LastUpdated", "LastUpdated");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("EnteredBy", "EnteredBy");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("CrediteTermId", "CrediteTermId");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("Approved", "Approved");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("DeliveryDate", "DeliveryDate");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("ETA", "ETA");
                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.ColumnMappings.Add("CommModeId", "CommModeId");


                                sqlBulkPromotionMaster.WriteToServer(dReader);
                                TempData["alertMessage"] = "Data Stored Successfully of PromotionMaster";


                                excelConnection.Close();


                            }


                        }


                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("LoadPriceExcel");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                TempData["alertMessage"] = "Exception Occured";
                return RedirectToAction("LoadPriceExcel");
            }
        }
```

dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); here it is throwing exception No Value is given for one or more required parameter.

All fields in Excel exactly match with  table.

Previously it was working now it is throwing error.

Comment: it seems like maybe one column in your Excel might miss a data value, where your database is not set to accept NULL.Some nice guy once told me to first import data in Temporary table, without any restriction and than transfer from tmp table to main table with data type casting. Check your data file or try other Excel sheet if you find something.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your first row (A1:ZZ1) have the headers of the table.